# Why doesn't emmisive material render in my camera?

Tags: rendering, emission

I'm trying to create a simple sky for a scene.  Right now I'm modelling it as a gradient texture applied to the inside of a sphere.  I made the shader emissive so that it does not cast a shadow and contributes ambient light to the scene.

Unfortunately, it does not show up when seen through the camera or in the final render.  How do I get my emissive shader to be seen?

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First thing that comes to mind is that it might be camera clipping (basically that your 'render distance' is too short).

[image]

Comment: That was it.  Thanks.